# Forcast fulfillment sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have came across with the requirement where I need to write sql query to fill stock from one location to another based on their warehouse rank and sales rank. 
Below is the scenario:
I have one table which is having surplus quantities of product A(table 1)
I have another table which is having required quantities(forecast) of product A (table 2).

I need to send product quantities from (table 1) A to (table 2 )B according to their rank (for A SOH_RNK , for B SLS_RNK)

**table 1:**

```
PROD_ID SOH_RNK QTY STORE_ID_A
A           1   30  30105
A           2   16  21168
A           3   10  21032
A           4   9   30118
A           9   6   30011
A           10  5   21190
A           13  2   21016
```

**table 2:**

```
PROD_ID SLS_RNK Forcast_QTY STORE_ID_B
A           1       15      21005
A           2       10      30019
A           3       11      21006
A           4       16      30001
A           5       11      21015
A           6       7       21004
```

**Expected output:**

```
Store_ID_B  Store_id_A  Transferred_Qty_from_A
21005           30105           15
30019           30105           10
21006           30105           5
21006           21168           6
30001           30105           0
30001           21168           10
30001           21032           6
21015           30105           0
21015           21168           0
21015           21032           4
21015           30118           7
21004           30105           0
21004           21168           0
21004           21032           0
21004           30118           2
21004           30011           5
```

So far I have tried with the making cross join but didnt help much . I am trying to avoid procedural approach as it will be row by row and I have records with 20 million of such .

Comment: there can be many number of combinations in which those conditions meet.

Comment: fulfillment of the store B will be based on the stock of Store A and its rank . for example  21005 store needs 15 quantities . so since soh_rnk for store 30105 is comes first so it will transfer the quantity from its stock .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to determine ranges of quantities in both tables, then join both tables based on these ranges to obtain a quantity of products sent from the source store to the destination store.

This is an example of query that calculates ranges for the first table (the query for the second table is similar to this one):

```
  select t1.*,
         coalesce(sum( qty ) 
             over ( order by soh_rnk 
                   range between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding),
             0) As range_start,
         sum( qty ) over ( order by soh_rnk ) As range_end
  from table1 t1

PROD_ID |SOH_RNK |QTY |STORE_ID_A |RANGE_START |RANGE_END |
--------|--------|----|-----------|------------|----------|
A       |1       |30  |30105      |0           |30        |
A       |2       |16  |21168      |30          |46        |
A       |3       |10  |21032      |46          |56        |
A       |4       |9   |30118      |56          |65        |
A       |9       |6   |30011      |65          |71        |
A       |10      |5   |21190      |71          |76        |
A       |13      |2   |21016      |76          |78        |
```

---

Now we can join records from both tables when two data ranges from both tables overlaps each other.
A formula for checking if two ranges overlap can be found here: http://www.soliantconsulting.com/blog/2016/03/determining-if-two-date-ranges-overlap


 It is: `NOT (EndA <= StartB or StartA >= EndB)`

The final query:

```
WITH  t1 AS (
  select t1.*,
         coalesce(sum( qty ) over ( order by soh_rnk range between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding),0) As range_start,
         sum( qty ) over ( order by soh_rnk ) As range_end
  from table1 t1
),
t2 As (
    select t2.*,
           coalesce(sum( forecast_qty ) over ( order by sls_rnk range between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding),0) As range_start,
           sum( forecast_qty ) over ( order by sls_rnk ) As range_end
    from table2 t2
)
SELECT 
       t1.store_id_a,
       t2.store_id_b,
       least( t1.range_end, t2.range_end ) - greatest( t1.range_start, t2.range_start ) As Transferred_Qty_from_A
FROM t1
join t2
-- NOT (EndA <= StartB or StartA >= EndB)
on not ( t1.range_end <= t2.range_start OR t1.range_start >= t2.range_end)
   and t1.prod_id = t2.prod_id
order by soh_rnk, sls_rnk
;
```

And a result of this query is:

```
STORE_ID_A |STORE_ID_B |TRANSFERRED_QTY_FROM_A |
-----------|-----------|-----------------------|
30105      |21005      |15                     |
30105      |30019      |10                     |
30105      |21006      |5                      |
21168      |21006      |6                      |
21168      |30001      |10                     |
21032      |30001      |6                      |
21032      |21015      |4                      |
30118      |21015      |7                      |
30118      |21004      |2                      |
30011      |21004      |5                      |
```

---

Unluckily I have no idea how to include records with `0` quantity in the resultset (when none of products were transfered from 1st to 2nd store).

Comment: Thanks for this innovative approach . This works like charm :)

Comment: @krokodilko I was just stumbled upon this question which is similar to mine . If I need to send product quantities from (table 1) A to (table 2 )B with minimum iteration .Will that be possible using interval overlap?