# Range sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to SQL. I am trying to write one query which is almost similar to [forcast-fulfillment-sql-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41344693/forcast-fulfillment-sql-query) but in my business need is to take `req_qty` `max_qty` based on running `reserve_qty` available at the `STORE_ID_B`

**Table:1**

```
STORE_ID_A  req_qty max_qty shop_rnk
1002            3       5   1
1003            5       8   2
1004            1       5   3
1005            3       5   5
1006            3       5   6
1007            3       5   8
1008            3       5   9
1009            3       5   10
1010            2       5   11
1011            3       5   12
1012            2       5   13
```

**Table 2:**

```
STORE_ID_B       reserve_qty    rnk
    500             10          1
    501             9           2
```

**Expected Output:**

```
STORE_ID_A  STORE_ID_B  release_qty
1002            500         3
1003            500         7
1004            501         1
1005            501         3
1006            501         5
```

For the first row STORE_ID_B reserve_qty =10 and `STORE_ID_A` `req_qty` 3 and max_qty 5 .As 10 does not between 3 and 5 so I need to take `req_qty` ie 3.
The second row, now balance `reserve_qty` is (10-3) =7 and it lies between 5 and 8 so I need to take `max_qty`. sending qty  will be based on the Store_ID_A and STORE_ID_B rank .

So far I have tried below .But didn't get the required output.Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
WITH  t1 AS (
  select t1.*,
         coalesce(sum( reserve_qty ) over ( order by rnk range between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding),0) As range_start,
         sum( reserve_qty ) over ( order by rnk ) As range_end
  from table1 t1
),
t2 As (
    select t2.*,
           coalesce(sum( req_qty ) over ( order by shop_rnk range between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding),0) As range_start,
           sum( req_qty ) over ( order by shop_rnk ) As range_end
    from table2 t2
)


    select t1.*,t2.* , t1.req_qty - coalesce(sum(er_rtl_dm..least( from_loc_rec.range_end, to_loc_rec.range_end ) - greatest( from_loc_rec.range_start, to_loc_rec.range_start )) OVER (
                               PARTITION BY from_loc_rec.vpn,from_loc_rec.color,from_loc_rec.loc_CD ORDER BY to_loc_rec.rnk rows BETWEEN unbounded preceding
                                             AND 1 preceding
                               ), 0) 
    FROM t1
    join t2
    on not ( t1.range_end <= t2.range_start OR t1.range_start >= t2.range_end)
```